# Every day, in a different time, there is no possibility to connect to SQL Server Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, named-pipes, windows-server-2012-r2

The issue: every day, in a different time, there is no possibility to connect to SQL Server.

2 days ago we've migrated to new server (from win server 2008 r2 to win server 2012 r2)

on the old win server 2008 everything worked fine and we have the same SQL Server congfiguration setting for the new one:

1. In SQL Server settings using shared memory only -- connections to SQL Server from a client running on the same computer.
2. Named Pipes and TCP/IP are disabled.
3. Server agent and server browser stopped

[image: congfiguration screenshot]

- Firewall is disabled.

In most of the time everything works without problems on the new server. 
The problem was identified by the applications which is trying to connect to the server and falls.

Log looks like this:

Event viewer application log:

2017-01-05 02:40:09.72 Server      Error: 26050, Severity: 17, State: 1.
2017-01-05 02:40:09.72 Server      Server local connection provider has stopped listening on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ] due to a failure. Error: 0xe8, state: 4. The server will automatically attempt to re-establish listening.
2017-01-05 02:40:54.10 spid24s     Server local connection provider has successfully re-established listening on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].

asp.net sites error log:

2017-01-06 00:10:23,545 [32] ERROR:
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

New server details:

- Windos Server 2012 r2 Standard
- SQL Server 2014 Express

Old server details:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- SQL Server 2008 Express

If you need any information, tell me please.

forgot to mention, that after win server reboot the issue dissapear on some time

**ADDITIANAL INFO**

1) Disabling named pipes as a **client protocol** does not seem to have any effect.

2) [SELECT net_transport FROM sys.dm_exec_connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivdVl.png)

3) I only see local connection information in my SQL Server error log:

2017-01-08 17:02:52.49 spid15s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].

2017-01-08 17:02:52.49 spid15s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].

as far as i know with named pipes enabled, I should see messages like '**Server named pipe provider** is ready...'

also i've found the info
"Shared memory is an implementation of a local named pipe. So messages from shared memory can have pipe information."

Comment: https://vijredblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/investigating-server-local-connection-provider-has-stopped-listening-on-pipesqllocalmssqlserver/

Comment: thank you fo the link, but I've already seen this article
i'm just trying to undestand why do i need to enable Named Pipes...most of time all works with Named Pipes disabled and on the old server we had the same configaration and no issues
what could be causing this behavior on the new one?

Comment: Can you just confirm: you are only ever connecting from the same computer? - never over the network? Your client libraries might actually be set up to use named pipes. ie. under 'SQL Native Client Configuration' make sure you don't have named pipes enabled... which leads me to this: can you go through the SQL Server log and confirm which protocol you are connecting on?

Comment: yes, SQL Server instance running on the same computer with the applications, so i use only shared memory - SQL server logs says:
2017-01-06 17:06:19.04 spid15s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2017-01-06 17:06:19.04 spid15s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ]. -- actually yes i have named pipes enabled under 'SQL Native Client Configuration' for both server new and old on

Comment: You said named pipes was disabled but the log says otherwise. This site http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-which-protocol-is-being-used-for-client-server-connectivity-in-sql-server/ suggests this query to check what the client is actually connecting on: `
SELECT net_transport FROM sys.dm_exec_connections;`. Find out what the client is actually connecting on. If it's connecting on named pipes but that's dropping out then that might explain it, and you'll need to ensure only shared memory is enabled for client and server.

Comment: Nick, thank you for the info! - i've added 'additional info' block above.  - Could it be the situations when the shared memory attempt failed, but errors indicate the client attempted named pipe?